# Using yq, delete any key whose scalar value is false

Tags: yaml, yq

I would like to delete all keys that have a scalar value of false, using https://github.com/mikefarah/yq:

### Input

```yaml
project: false_deletion
fields:
  name:
    numeric: false
    value: John
  age:
    value: 25
    numeric: true
  address:
    value: 123 Main St
    numeric: false
```

### Desired output

```yaml
project: false_deletion
fields:
  name:
    value: John
  age:
    value: 25
    numeric: true
  address:
    value: 123 Main St
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yq e 'del(.. | select(. == false))' input
```

Will [`del()`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/delete) all those keys where the value is `false`.

Output:

```yaml
project: false_deletion
fields:
  name:
    value: John
  age:
    value: 25
    numeric: true
  address:
    value: 123 Main St
```

Comment: Thanks. I just posted a general question about improving my yq skills, if you're interested!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788597/strategies-for-becoming-more-proficient-with-yq